# cannot import name 'PROT_READ' from 'mmap'

Tags: python, python-packaging

I am trying to use pypcie to write a small piece of code,
I have installed the package in vs code using pip, but when I try to run the code
it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\'user'\OneDrive\desktop\Git Repos\learnpython_org\pyPCIE_playground.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pypcie import Device
  File "C:\Users\'user'\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pypcie\_init_.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .device import Device
  File "C:\Users\'user'\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pypcie\device.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .bar import Bar
  File "C:\Users\'user'\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pypcie\bar.py", line 3, in <module>
    from mmap import mmap, PROT_READ, PROT_WRITE, PAGESIZE
ImportError: cannot import name 'PROT_READ' from 'mmap' (unknown location)
```

the line that I have traced this back to is in the pyPCIe package that I have installed

```
from mmap import mmap, PROT_READ, PROT_WRITE, PAGESIZE
```

Am I missing a step in setup to use the package properly?
I assumed mmap is a built-in package and not needed to isntall via pip, since when I try to run

```
pip install mmap
```

it returns `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mmap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [pyPCIe](https://github.com/heikoengel/pyPCIe) package you're trying to use will only work on Linux, as you can see in the [classifiers list on its PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/pyPCIe/).

You're evidently on Windows, so that package will *not* work.

Comment: Right I thought it meant its built on Linux, quite new to this so I still don't quite know how things work, thanks alot